# How do I run robocopy without copying extended attribute information?

Tags: scripting, attributes, filesystems, batch-file, robocopy

Greetings,

I've got a bat script which copies certain information from a computer onto a USB hard drive using Robocopy.  The hard drive is FAT formatted and therefore doesn't support directories with extended attributes, leading me to robocopy error 282 [as described here](http://forums.hexus.net/thecus-care-hexus/121981-n5200pro-error-mounted-file-system-does-not-support-extended-attributes.html).

How do I tell robocopy to copy all the attribute information EXCEPT for the extendable attributes?

**I still need help, but, some helpful info from the googling ive done thus far**

- Robocopy Command-Line Options: http://www.ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html
- What is an Extended File Attribute: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes
- Windows Hotfix (which would be great if I wasn't copying to a USB hard drive): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329145/en-us

**EDIT:** *Wow, the file system isn't FAT, I was wrong.  Its RAW.*

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? Do you get an error message when extendable attributes are copied? Or can't you access the files after the copy?

Comment: Good call.  Added (it was error 282)

Answer (score 1):

I found I only got the 282 error when copying direcories with robocopy. So I used xcopy with /T /E to create the directory structure. I was then able to use robocpy to copy all the files without error.

Answer (score 0):

Convert FAT USB hard drive to NTFS using convert command (converting in this direction won't delete the data):
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456984.aspx

eg:

```
convert e: /fs:ntfs
```